How to investigate MFT corruption?(NTFS partition)
I'm wondering if there are some ways to investigate MFT corruption on a NTFS partition stored on a SSD.
Partition got corrupted after a BSOD. Many files have inconsistent contents although the whole files/folders structure seems to be present(after chkdsk run), I wasn't able to notice missing files/folders.
chkdsk is not able to fix them, it fills them with inconsistent data, or single character strings.
chkdsk was only able to allow me to open directories that otherwise the OS would say that they are corrupted and unreadable.
I understand that there is a backup for the MFT.
Can I compare these 2 versions of MFT and observe the differences?
Can I temporarily use the backup MFT to see if files(or some files) are still corrupted?
